# R: Generar valores en nuevas columnas en Dataframe a partir de Nombres de columnas

Tags: r, formato

Saludos a todos,

Verán, Tengo un gran dataframe, y los nombres de las columnas tienen un formato tipo "XXX_YYY_ZZZ", pudiendo tomar XXX, YYY o ZZZ diferentes categorías/factores. Me gustaría hacer un dataframe de sólo 4 columnas, siendo las columnas "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ" y los valores de las columnas. previas.

Me preguntaba si alguien conoce alguna manera sencilla de hacer todo esto.

Por ejemplo, el data frame actual tiene este aspecto:

> "CYT_CD40L_exp1"   |    "MEMB_QVD_exp1"  |  "ORG_FasL_exp3"
>
> ```
>    0              |        2           |       4
>    1              |        3           |       5
> ```

y me gustaría poder convertir la tabla a:

> Valor | "XXX" | "YYY"  | "ZZZ"
>
> 0    | "CYT"      |  "CD40L"   |  "exp1"
>
> 1    | "CYT"      |  "CD40L"   |  "exp1"
>
> 2    | "MEMB"      |  "QVD"   |  "exp1"
>
> 3    | "MEMB"      |  "QVD"   |  "exp1"
>
> 4    | "ORG"      |  "FasL"   |  "exp3"
>
> 5    | "ORG"      |  "FasL"   |  "exp3"

Sé que puedo separar los nombres de las columnas en con `strsplit(colnames(df), sep"_")[y]`, pero es muy tedioso ordenar todos los valores.

Espero haberme explicado suficientemente ^^U. Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ouuiea, 
la forma más compacta y simple que se me ocurre es usando dos funciones de la librería `tidyverse::`. Trabajo sobre tu ejemplo mínimo, si está bien hecho debería escalar para tus datos reales. Uso el operador binario `%>%` para encadenar funciones, pero podrías hacerlo de otro modo.

```
#Cargo la librería
library(tidyverse)
# Creo el df foo con los datos el ejemplo.
tribble(~CYT_CD40L_exp1,~MEMB_QVD_exp1, ~ORG_FasL_exp3, 
                  0,             2,              4,
                  1,             3,              5) -> foo

#En dos pasos cambio la estructura.
gather(foo) %>% 
  separate(key, into=c("XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ"))
```

¿Cómo fuciona? `gather()` pasa el data.frame a formato largo: pares de claves y valores.

`separate()` toma una columna con cadenas separadas por un separador y crea varias columnas, una con cada cadena separada. Es necesario especificar los nombres de las nuevas columnas con el argumento `into=`, al que pasas un vector de caracteres encomillados definido con `c()`. `separate()` "adivina" cuál es el separador, en este caso `_`, pero si hay ambigüedad es posible pasarlo con el argumento `sep= "separador"`.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Usando simplemente el paquete base puedes resolverlo de la siguiente forma:

```
df <- read.table(text = "CYT_CD40L_exp1 MEMB_QVD_exp1 ORG_FasL_exp3
0 2 4
1 3 5", header = TRUE)

newdf <- data.frame(Valor=numeric(), XXX=character(), YYY=character(), ZZZ=character())
for (col in colnames(df)) {
    newdf <- rbind(newdf, merge(df[, col], t(c(unlist(strsplit(col, "_"))))))
}
newdf
```

La salida:

```
  x   V1    V2   V3
1 0  CYT CD40L exp1
2 1  CYT CD40L exp1
3 2 MEMB   QVD exp1
4 3 MEMB   QVD exp1
5 4  ORG  FasL exp3
6 5  ORG  FasL exp3
```

Básicamente creamos un nuevo `data.frame` con la estructura esperada y por cada nombre de columna (`colnames(df)`) "spliteamos" los valores en una lista que luego transponemos para que nos queden los tres valores a modo de fila, luego hacemos un `merge()` con los datos de la propia columna y la fila final la agregamos al nuevo `dataframe` con `rbind()`